# Debian crontab doesn't run scripts

Tags: debian, cron

I'm having problems with setting my crontab script to run. When I execute it manually it works. My crontab file looks like this:

```
17 13           1-31 * 1-7              /myscripts/svn_backup_script.sh
```

Could anyone tell me if there are any more nessesary steps needed for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

check if your script is executable, if not, set it

```
chmod u+x /myscripts/svn_backup_script.sh
```

you can also redirect your script output to a file to check if it shows any errors

```
17 13 1-31 * 1-7    /myscripts/svn_backup_script.sh &> /tmp/svn_backup_script.log
```

I guess your cron daemon is running

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not having ".sh" on the end of the script name, ISTR run-parts doesn't like it

Comment: This does matter for things using run-parts(8).  It would be a problem if it were just a script being left in /etc/cron.daily for instance, but in this case it is fine.  Regular crontab entries have nothing to do with run-parts

Comment: thanks stew, i thought that might be the case, but "worth a try" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look on your environment variables, PATH and SHELL. You can define another default shell in this way. When I used crontab an OCSInventory script to run, it helped me.